# Textframe2.Orientation error when setting value

Tags: excel, vba, orientation

I am using Excel 365 and I am trying to set the orientation on the text frame within a shape to 45 degrees.  The textframe2.orientation property says it should take a value anywhere from 90 to -90 but it kicks a Subscript out of Range error if I put any value in the code besides one of the mso standards.  I need to figure out why the property won't take a value for a setting.  The code section is as follows:

```
' Place redaction block
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Left, Top, Width, Height)
    s.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    s.Fill.Transparency = 0.85
    With s.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 1.5
    End With
    If Worksheets("Files").Cells(rowct, 10).Value = 31 Or Worksheets("Files").Cells(rowct, 10).Value = 35 Then
        With s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .Name = "Arial Black"
            .Size = 200
        End With
        With s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            .Transparency = 0.85
            .Solid
        End With
        With s
            .TextFrame2.Orientation = msoTextOrientationUpward
            .TextFrame2.WordWrap = msoTrue
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = ExText
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: I think the docs are just wrong here. I don't think you can do this manually.

Comment: A workaround might be to add a textbox on top of the shape and rotate that?

Comment: The Docs are just simply wrong here. The Orientation of a Worksheet Range can take other numeric values, but not this Object

Comment: ^ To echo that... if the docs were true, then Excel would have to magically distinguish between, for example, 2 degrees and `msoTextOrientationUpward`, [which is equivalent to 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msotextorientation)... yeah the docs are just wrong.

Comment: Thanks BigBen and MacroMarc for the validation that I wasn't completely crazy.  I thought the docs might be in error too, but not enough experience to trust that.  I will look at adding a textbox on top and rotating that.  Thanks.